# Show last picture taken in ImageView not working

Tags: android, android-camera

I've been trying to include a ImageView in my activity to show the last picture taken with the camera. The ImageView is basically a miniature on the right bottom corner that will later serve as a onclick intent to the app gallery.. and I want it to show the last photo taken and when you open the app, the most recent photo in its directory. This is the java code section for this:

```
private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
    PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                //
                final ImageView GalleryShortcut = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.galleryshortcut);
                BitmapFactory.Options scalingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                scalingOptions.inSampleSize = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width / GalleryShortcut.getMeasuredWidth();
                final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, scalingOptions);
                GalleryShortcut.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                GalleryShortcut.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            Preview.refreshCamera(Camera);
        }
    };
```

And this is the .xml ImageView Code:

```
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/galleryshortcut"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>
```

Crashlog:

> 09-14 11:09:23.784    2617-2617/cam.fornax.fornaxcam E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: cam.fornax.fornaxcam, PID: 2617
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {cam.fornax.fornaxcam/cam.fornax.fornaxcam.FRNXCamera}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>               at android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:495)
>               at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:341)
>               at cam.fornax.fornaxcam.FRNXCamera.onResume(FRNXCamera.java:209)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
>               at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try calling:

`GalleryShortcut.invalidate()` after you call `GalleryShortcut.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

If that doesn't work, you'll have to run the image-setting in a handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It didn't work for me. Is there a handler tutorial for this? I am a beginner and I couldn't find any link that helped me.

Comment: Look at the threading / ui android docs: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html